# How can I implement greylisting in Exchange?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

My search only turned up commercial products that add this feature to Exchange. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Tarpitting is enabled by default in Exchange Server 2010 but there's no greylisting functionality that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange doesn't have Greylisting out of the box.  The closest you can get is to finalize a version of the MSDN sample agent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb402057(v=exchg.140).aspx

A custom agent (like that one) could be installed on your Edge Transport (assuming you are running one) to implement some greylisting.  But that is sample MSDN code, you'd want to triple check how it works and know that it is **not** officially supported code.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, Microsoft has intentionally removed all sources on the Internet to the Exchange 2010 Transport Agent SDK downloads with its samples - but there is a guy which has created a greylisting transport agent in github: https://github.com/semack/GreylistAgent.

Hope this helps sombody.